# update fragment when taskadapter is empty

Tags: android, fragment, adapter

I have a fragment that has a listView which has an adapater, in the adapter class, there are buttons that remove objects from the adapter and then the adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged();  In the event that the adapter is empty I want the fragment to know and do something, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: u want to show info when the adapter is empty?

Comment: yes, I want to say the list is empty

Comment: A toast or a textview,etc?

Comment: Once the last listview item is deleted i want to display a textview that says that there are no items to display

Answer (score 0):

u can set a textview in your fragment xml file.Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="No item yet"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_notebook"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the adapter is empty,you can use textView.setVisible(VISIBLE).( you can search name).When the adapter has some items,you can use textView.setVisible(...)

Well,you can do like this in your fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    // set up listview
    if(mDataList.size()==0){
        mListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        YourAdapter mAdapter = new YourAdapter(mDataList...)
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return rootView;
}

public void deleteItem(int position){
    Data item = mDataList.get(position);
    mDataList.remove(item);
    if(mDataList.size()==0){
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        mAdapter.notifyDataChanged();
    }
}
public void addItem(Data item){
   .....
}
```

Comment: I know how to set a textview to visible, what I am asking is how the fragment can know when the textview is empty

Comment: every time you use notifyDatachanged,you can check the size of data, when the size is 0,you can set textview visible

Comment: but i type notifyDataCHanged in the adapter and the textview is in the fragment

Comment: you use adapter.notifydatachange?the adapter is typed in your fragment too,because the listview is typed in your fragment

Comment: i only use the notifydatachanged in the adapter, never in the fragment, how do I know in the fragment when data in the adapter is changed?